# Remove a watermark from video

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to remove a static watermark with a dynamic background.

In fact, I have a video with a logo that is in the top right corner and the background is always changing. I already tried the "content aware fill" feature of Adobe After Effects, but it doesn't work. I think this feature is good when your object is moving but in my case the object (watermark) is static.

I then tried Photoshop by selecting the area of the watermark & then *"Fill → Unselect"*. This is working, but I have to do it frame by frame. My video lasts 7 minutes with 60 frames / second, so you can imagine that I cannot do that frame by frame.

Is there a way to do it automatically for a video? If possible with step by step explanations since I'm a newbie to those tools. I even created a Photoshop action with *"Fill → Unselect → Next frame"*, but still I have to execute them one by one...

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you the copyright holder of the video?

Comment: @Scott - presumably if they owned the video, they'd also have access to the pre-watermark version ;) [Interestingly, if totally off-topic, my TV will remove watermarks/TV idents on the fly. Clever, i say:)

Comment: Not necessarily @Tetsujin -- original could have been lost with no backup.

Comment: Yes, I am. The problem is the original video was cut to something shorter & I found myself with a video with the older logo of the company that I need to remove.. I do not have access to the original video by the way.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because it's a video editing question which belongs on Video Production Stack Exchange. Sorry about that.